# MuPAD (MATLAB symbolic toolbox) export to LaTeX

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to export a entire MuPAD notebook into LaTeX in the same fashion like Mathematica does? I am familiar with MuPAD latex command but it seems (at least on the first glance) that it is less convenient than export command in Mathematica.

**Edit** 
As requested minimal working example of MuPAD notebook.

```
diff(sin(x), x)
  cox(x)
generate::TeX(hold(diff(sin(x),x)))
  "\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin\!\left(x\right)"
generate::TeX(diff(sin(x),x))
  "\cos\!\left(x\right)"
```

Instead of exporting command and the output separately I would just like to export the entire notebook.

P.S. The MuPAD language has a Pascal-like syntax and allows imperative, functional, and object-oriented programming. Its domains and categories are object-oriented classes that allow overriding and overloading methods and operators, inheritance, and generic algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `publish` features of Matlab. This is from matlab documentation

> Publishing Results
>
> Publishing to HTML, XML, LaTeX, and Formats for
>   Word and PowerPoint Applications
>
> You can publish M-files to HTML, XML, LaTeX, and to formats for
>   Microsoft Word and Microsoft® PowerPoint® applications. The published
>   documents can include code, formatted comments, and results, such as
>   graphs in Figure windows. Use cells and cell publishing features in
>   the Editor/Debugger. For details, see Overview of Publishing MATLAB
>   Code in the online documentation.
>
> Demo of New Publishing Features.  If you are using the Help browser,
>   watch the new Publishing M Code from the Editor video demo for an
>   overview of the major functionality. Notebook
>
> If you currently use Notebook, consider using cell publishing from the
>   Editor instead, which provides more features and flexibility for most
>   applications.

For more details, check [demo video](http://www.mathworks.in/support/2011a/matlab/7.12/demos/PublishingfromtheEditor_viewlet_swf.html) and documentation of matlab.

Comment: very useful answer. Thank you so much! I will need to experiment with it but it seems that your answer implies that publishing works only for M-files. MuPAD uses separate language and interface. Does the same applies for MuPAD code?

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: Can you provide a minimal mupad code?. Above feature can be applied to any code that runs from matlab.

Comment: I apologize for not putting minimal working example earlier. It is added now.

Comment: Whether Mupad of mackichan is same as this. If so, you can have a try with scientific workplace or scientific notebook (http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/sw.html~mainFrame)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to use to use the .m file method.

However, I exported the MuPad to HTML/XML and then converted the html file using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/README.html) to latex. The input commands are enclosed in brackets. Using some regular expressions, you can put those commands in the `alltt` package's environment.